# Will it be possible to use ReactJS Native for Ubuntu Touch development?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Facebook are developing React Native for iOS and Android development. This seems to be a game-changer for mobile app development.

I guess Facebook won't expend resources to develop a React Native bridge for Ubuntu Touch, at least not while Ubuntu Phone market penetration is neglible compared to Android and iOS.

Ubuntu SDK supports QML and HTML5, which are both similar to React Native, in some ways. Nevertheless, React Native looks tremendously exciting for mobile app development, and will be opensourced by Facebook. Moreover, Facebook have announced Nuclide.io, and Atom-based IDE for React Native and web development.

Is Canonical considering integrating React Native for Ubuntu Touch development?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yes, it seems that they are working on it.

the source code:

https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/react-native

the blog entry:

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/blog/2016/08/05/introducing-react-native-ubuntu/